# What determines fleet size?

Tags: endless-space

I have a hostile neighbor whose fleet's are more powerful than any of mine. The problem isn't that I don't have good enough ships, but that my fleet sizes are too small.

With my best ships I can only merge two at a time into a fleet.

Is there a way to increase the size of a fleet?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Fleet size is determined by **Command Points Cap**, found on the left (Diplomacy and Trading) branch of the tech tree.

[image: Fleetsize]

*Clicking on a fleet and looking at the number next to the satellite dish icon is a quick way to see the fleet size limts. Here 16 of 16 slots are used.*

Note: Researching **Quantum Communications** unlocks **C3 Systems** which gives you `+2` cap for each new ship class acquired (ship classes are unlocked in the bottom tree, **Exploration and Expansion**).

Comment: Academy cap is for your HERO/LEADER limit. Has nothing to do with max fleet size. Other than that, your answer is correct.

Comment: Your answer is missing one factor. There are racial bonus/maluses that change maximum fleet size by 2.